# Sybase SQL Anywhere driver throws NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0, nullreferenceexception, sqlanywhere

I have the problem, that in my multithreading application, the SQL Anywhere 12 driver throws NullReferenceExceptions. The Exception is always thrown at different points, but always during opening a connection. There are a maximum of 5 open connections. The stack trace is the following:

[image]

I have no idea why this happens.

Does anyone else has similar problems? Currently i have no idea.

**EDIT**:

The error is not really reproducible, because some times the app runs correct for two hours or a day and some times only 10min.

Comment: which version 12.? of SQL Anywhere ADO.Net driver are you using?

Comment: @NeillVerreynne we use SQL 12 databases, but SQL 16 driver. The driver has the following version: `16.0.0.20524`. The DB has the following version: `12.0.1.3579`

Comment: Well, the SAConnectionPoolManager were not thread safe when multiple threads are trying to allocate/close multiple connection pools. This was fixed (so they say) in version 16.0.0.1431 and 12.0.1.3851.

Comment: @NeillVerreynne if you make an answer from your comment, i will accept it. The problem should be solved. I've recognized that one of our customers use `3994` and they have no problems :) Thank you very very very much...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the SAConnectionPoolManager were not thread safe when multiple threads are trying to allocate/close multiple connection pools. This was fixed (so they say) in version 16.0.0.1431 and 12.0.1.3851.